# use mshtml HTMLDocument to modify DOM and display in IE browser extension/ BHO

Tags: c#, image, internet-explorer, dom, mshtml

I'm working with C#.NET: mshtml.HTMLDocument, mshtml.HTMLImg etc.

What I'm trying to do is modify the DOM and reflect the change in the browser. e.g.

```
           HTMLDocument doc = WebBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;
           HTMLImg img;
           for (int i = 0; i < doc.images.length; i++)
           {
               img = doc.images.item(i) as HTMLImg;
               ProcessImg(ref img);                   
           }
```

Unfortunately the processed/modified image is not displayed in the browser. I suppose Ineed to I save the image locally and change the src attrib of the IMG tag. But apart from not successding (help please!) to do so, I fear that it won't be displayed as well. How do I tell the browser to update (if necessary at all)

Cheers, folks!
Bert
What approach would you take?

Comment: can you specify 'reliability reasons'

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you can't change an existing image without changing the SRC attribute. You should share your not-working code for that for folks to see.

Please keep in mind that writing browser extensions for IE in .NET is strongly discouraged for performance and reliability reasons.

Comment: How do I refresh the browser to show the modified SRC attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w) out, its definitely possible to modify the displayed page, as I am doing it with a plugin I am working on.

Basically the class implements IObjectWithSite and IOleCommandTarget, the former allowing your code to subscribe to browsing action and the latter hooking up the UI action.  Code in the example link sets/clears an HTMLDocument that is the actual document you want to modify.

**edit**: 
I think that despite appearances HTMLDocument is not in the mshtml namespace, but actually in System.Windows.Forms. R# says otherwise, but the whole mshtml namespace feels like an exercise in misdirection by indirection with redirection and indigestion thrown in for good measure.